# how to set default text string - android

Tags: android, text, message, default

actually humm...let me try to explain...
I was following the tutorial for android app starters and
with this code the EditText part the there will be a default message which was set in the string but the default message is grey and when we use the phone and click on the EditText part the grey message will be gone....I tried doing this again but what I get is that the default message is black and when I click on the EditText on the phone the message will stay instead of gone which means I have to delete the message manually to enter what is wanted.  Anyone can give me a hand with it?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"  
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/edit_message" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send"
    android:onClick="sendMessage" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The above is something I want and the below is what I have,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


/*have a few more EditText, Buttons and TextView here but don't think it's relevant so didn't paste*/

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_percentage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:text="@string/edit_percentage" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/edit_percentage"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
    android:text="@string/button3" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I did thought if it's because of the relativelayout and linearlayout but didn't seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want `hint`. Add this line

```
android:hint="@string/edit_percentage"
```

instead of

```
android:text="@string/edit_percentage"
```

Comment: ah! great...omg I have been comparing both codes for awhile to see what are the differences...tried so many and I missed the word hint and text!
Still need 4 more minutes before I can choose this to be the correct answer...thank you...thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:text` attribute.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:text="@string/edit_message" />
```